# How to create a dynamic dispatch client using apache CXF

Tags: client, cxf

I want to use apache CXF to build my client. Unfortunately, I do not see a way by which it allows me to dispatch a client dynamically based on the port and operation name. If there is a huge wsdl, JaxWsDynamicClientFactory would create classes for all services contained in it which is an overhead that I'd like to avoid.

I found a similar implementation in JAX-WS. Is there any api in CXF that would do the same?

Comment: JAX-WS is a _specification_ that CXF _implements_.

Answer (score 0):

CXF supports the JAX-WS [Dispatch API](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-dispatch-api.html), which is a low-level interface to SOAP.

That means you can create a `Dispatch` that represents a particular port-type on a service and then invoke the methods by building the message

```java
// Set things up...
Service s = ...
Dispatch<DOMSource> dispatch =
        s.createDispatch(portName, // << a QName!
                DOMSource.class, Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);

// Construct the request message here
Node response = dispatch.invoke(new DOMSource(request)).getNode();
// Understand the response message here
```

Of course, that then means you've got to work with the DOM for the messages, which is highly annoying. I think that's the part of tooling that's *really* worthwhile.

Comment: To turn my code into something that works, you will need a great many service-specific parameters so that the right message gets sent to the right address. I'd just tool up the WSDL and stop worrying about it…

Comment: True that we can use the above piece of code and it works perfect. But I want to implement advance features like WS Security, SAML etc which are not supported by plain JAX-WS client, where as CFX which is built on JAX-WS does support.  Or do we have a way where in we can configure security in JAX-WS i.e; by using CXF and JAX-WS in a combination?